# closing previous terminals after restarting the script on linux

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I have a python script which aims to start a shell script and if it already works, the script should end the shell script and restart it. But the terminals won't shut when I kill the processes of previous case. What should I do?

```
import subprocess
import tempfile

cmd = "sudo pidof sudo ./l1_run.sh"

with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tempf:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=tempf,shell=True)
    proc.wait()
    tempf.seek(0)
    process_ids = tempf.read()
    process_ids = process_ids.decode("utf-8")
    print(process_ids)
    
if (len(process_ids) > 0):
    subprocess.run(["sudo kill -s SIGCHLD",process_ids], shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)    
    subprocess.run(["sudo kill -9",process_ids], shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)

subprocess.run(["sudo gnome-terminal -- ./l1_run.sh"], shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
```